# Compiling c program with MinGW causes cc1.exe fatal error

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64

I installed MinGW-w64 using win-builds.
It all went ok but then when I compile a file using

> `gcc -Wall -o prog.exe main.c`

I get this error

> `cc1.exe: fatal error: Files/win-builds-1.5.0/include: No such file or directory` 
>   `compilation terminated.`

I have updated gcc path. I get the same error when I try to build on eclipse.
The location where win-builds put all the files is `C:\Program Files\win-builds-1.5.0\` and the folder `\include\` exists.

My guess is that `cc1.exe` is trying to access `C:\Program Files\win-builds-1.5.0\include` but, for some reason it is separating `C:\Program` of `Files\win-builds-1.5.0\include`.

How can I get the compiler to work?
[image: Error]

**EDIT:**

Here is the code to be compiled

```
/*
 * main.c
 *
 *  Created on: 13/06/2018
 *      Author: haslima
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT:

when I run `gcc -v -c -o prog.exe main.c` I get this output:

```
Reading specs from c:/program files/win-builds-1.5.0/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.3/configure --prefix=/opt/windows_64 --with-sysroot=/opt/windows_64 --libdir=/opt/windows_64/lib64 --mandir=/opt/windows_64/man --infodir=/opt/windows_64/info --enable-shared --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-checking=release --enable-libgomp --with-system-zlib --with-python-dir=/lib64/python2.7/site-packages --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libssp --with-gnu-ld --verbose --enable-java-home --with-java-home=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm/jre --with-jvm-root-dir=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm --with-jvm-jar-dir=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm/jvm-exports --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-antlr-jar='/home/adrien/projects/win-builds-1.5/slackware64-current/d/gcc/antlr-*.jar' --disable-java-awt --disable-gtktest --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-o' 'prog.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 c:/program files/win-builds-1.5.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\program files\win-builds-1.5.0\bin\../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/ -D_REENTRANT -IC:/Program Files/win-builds-1.5.0/include main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip prog.exe -version -o C:\Users\hasli\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnpAzB7.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.3 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.3, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 0.8.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files/win-builds-1.5.0/lib64/gcc/../../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/windows_64/opt/windows_64/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files/win-builds-1.5.0/lib64/gcc/../../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files/win-builds-1.5.0/lib64/gcc/../../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/windows_64/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\program files\win-builds-1.5.0\bin\../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include
 c:\program files\win-builds-1.5.0\bin\../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include-fixed
 c:\program files\win-builds-1.5.0\bin\../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
cc1.exe: fatal error: Files/win-builds-1.5.0/include: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: try a main.c without any includes in it.

Comment: Does *main.c* contain `#include`s that reference those paths? Could you add its code? Also what does `set I` output in *cmd*?

Comment: @johnelemans tried it. The same problem occurred. The only include was `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @CristiFati I added the code. As you can see simpler is impossible. Running `set I`in cmd I get `Environment variable I not defined`

Comment: Hmm then those **include** paths are somewhere in *gcc*'s config (files?). There they should be doublequoted. Or "*win-builds*" (don't know what that is) was mentioned. Maybe there.

Comment: @CristiFati, what paths? The path to gcc is defined.

Comment: "gcc -v -c main.c" might give some interesting output. But unfortunately, it seems gcc is incorrectly configured and might need to be reinstalled.

Comment: @CristiFati, looked for gcc configs file and find none. Win-builds is the way ti install MinGW-64w as instructed [here](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)

Comment: @aschepler I added the output.
Actually I found the MinGW-w64 somehow strange. I followed the instructions read [here](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [[MinGW]: Getting Started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) (including **bolds**):

> MinGW may have problems with paths containing spaces, and if not, usually other programs used with MinGW will experience problems with such paths. Thus, we **strongly recommend** that you **do not install MinGW in any location with spaces in the path name reference**. You should avoid installing into any directory or subdirectory having names like "Program Files" or "My Documents", etc.

So, the solution is pretty straightforward:

- Uninstall your current version (might not be necessary, but there's no point keeping something broken)
- Make sure to read **all installation requirements / notes**
- Install it in a *SPACE* free *dir*

I should have thought of this sooner, as I don't install stuff in default dirs (e.g. I have *MinGW* installed in *"f:\Install\pc064\MinGW\MinGW-W64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0"*).

Comment: Thank you very much! The website you provided is the MinGW version and not the MinGW-w64. Although your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there any difference (well, besides the (*x86* / *x64*) architecture)? Actually, it's not *MinGW* but *gcc* (*cc1* port) that's faulty.

Comment: I guess not. Your solution was just perfect

Comment: Glad to be helpful! Honestly, I'm puzzled I couldn't figure it out sooner since I encountered this issue in the (far) past.

Comment: Probably yesterday you had the same problem as I did. I think that yesterday the website you suggested wasn't online. I tried to install the MinGW version and the website was not online.